# question about polynomials, algebra

Tags: polynomials

I have an assignment about the following:
Consider f(x) ∈ K[x] a non-zero polynomial of degree n and a ∈ K
a given element. Show that f(x) can be written as

$$f(x) = \sum_{r=0}^{n} a_r (x-a)^r $$ with $a_r$ ∈ K
i have an idea doiing it by induction on n, but i'm kinda lost, a hint will help me so much

Comment: "*a non-zero polynomial of degree $n$*" $\;-\;$ But the $f(x)$ you wrote has degree $k$. $\;$ "*a hint will help*" $\;-\;$ Hint: $x^k = \big((x-\alpha) + \alpha\big)^k$.

Comment: is the first time i post something, sorry, im gonna correct that